# Google sheets -- format rows x color if column A is x/y/z value

Tags: google-sheets, gs-conditional-formatting

I have a google sheet and it looks something like this.

```
# | quant | percent
1 | 10    | 10%
2 | 5     | 5%
3 | 10    | 10%
...
22| 3     | 3%
```

Etc

What I want to do is for EACH row, paint columns A/B/C the same color as column A.  Column A should be:  Green if # < 5,  Yellow if between 5 and 10.  Red if >10.

Thus column A should look something like this but with all columns having the same color as this row:

[image: Sheet]

Is this even possible

Comment: Conditional formatting will do this easily

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After an actual 2 hours of googling here's a rule that can use the fill handle to satisfy this

```
=IF($A:$A<=5, true)
```

And then adapt for between / greater than.

Comment: `=$A1<=5` should do the same. Conditional formatting when applied to a range, checks one cell at once. this is because you need dollar sign to keep column A calculated.